# AppSmith Self Hosted: Not able to upload file using file picker widget

Tags: appsmith

I am trying to upload a file using the AppSmith File Picker widget. But it always shows an error: Payload too large. File Size Can not exceed 100 MB. It happens even if I am uploading a file of 2 MB. Can anyone help me with this?